# Removing a Message Box in Subtotal Block-Magento

Tags: magento

I've set up a rule in Magento for free shipping set for a specific category which is set at a specific price.

It runs, but there is an issue with the subtotal block.
When I get to the check out page of my site and then I take a look down at my subtotal block, a message appears. `"Add $0.05 to your cart and receive FREE shipping!"` but I want to remove this.
*(I set the rule for $100 for free shipping).*

I'm not sure where this message is calling it from or if I set up the rule incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Install Magento Debug extension from here http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magneto-debug.html
and Then Turn On TEMPLATE HINTS. You will see the phtml file from which it is rendered.

Comment: I have downloaded the extension and it has been helpful. Still looking for the source of the message and I believe I'm close to the location. Thank you for the helpful hint.